# Is it safe to cast between B* and D* if D contains an object of type B as its first member?

Tags: pointers, casting, alias, d

Consider the following:

```
struct B { int x; }
struct D { B b; int y; }

void main() {
    auto b = cast(B*) new D();
    writeln(b.x == b.x);
    auto d = cast(D*) b;
    writeln(b.x == d.b.x);
}
```

Is this program guaranteed to write "true" twice? I couldn't find these rules anywhere in the D language reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structs in D "work like they do in C", so you can have reasonable expectations on their internal layout. Be wary of [hidden members of nested structs](http://dlang.org/struct.html#nested), though.

Casting from `D` to `B` should be fine. It is not safe to cast in the other direction, because `y` will then refer to something after the original `B` variable.

A simpler, safe way to cast from `D*` to `B*` is to take `D.b`'s address (`B* b = &d.b`).